# Home key go to start of line in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, key, keyboard-shortcuts

Where is the option in Visual Studio to make the Home key go to the start of the line?

Right now you have to do

<kbd>Home</kbd>,<kbd>Home</kbd>

or

<kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>

i'd prefer that home goes to the start of the line. i saw it before, but now i cannot find it.

Comment: Good question. And more importantly, why isn't that the default?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Tools/Customize/Keyboard,  Reassign the "Home" key from Edit.LineStart" to "Edit.LineFirstColumn"

**Edit by OP:** You must change **Scope** to **Text Editor** before this will work.

---

**Visual Studio 2010**

Visual Studio 2010 removed the *"scope"* option. Instead you want the *"Use new shortcut in"* option:

[image]

Comment: You cannot reassign the "Home" key. 

You push the "Home" key as the key you want to assign, and nothing happens.

Comment: Update: You can update the `Home` key, but only **after** you change the **Use new shortcut in** option to `Text Editor`. So intuitive.

Comment: In visual studio 2017 the option is called Edit.LineStartAfterIndentation.

Answer (score 6):

From asking the same question on MSDN forums:

TaylorMichaelL said:

> The command you are interested in is
>   Edit.LineFirstColumn.  **You'll want to
>   change the scope to be the Text
>   Editor.**  You should remove any
>   existing shortcut key associated with
>   the command first.  If you don't
>   change the scope then the Home key
>   won't work.  Then try using the Home
>   key.  It should work.
>
> Michael Taylor - 9/18/08
>   http://p3net.mvps.org

Changing the **Scope** to **Text Editor** was the missing piece in the puzzle.

- Go to Tools/Customize/Keyboard
- Change Scope to "**Text Editor**".
- Reassign the "Home" key from **Edit.LineStart** to **Edit.LineFirstColumn**