# Home key go to start of line in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Where is the option in Visual Studio Code to make the Home key go to the start of the line?

Right now you have to do

<kbd>Home</kbd>,<kbd>Home</kbd>

or

<kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>

i'd prefer that home goes to the start of the line.

### Bonus Chatter

File → Preferences → Keyboard Shortcuts:

[image]

### Bonus Reading

- [Home key go to start of line in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/83808/12597)

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to (windows) File-> Preferences-> Keyboard Shortcuts
2. type cursorHome in search and right click -> remove keybinding on both `cursorHome` and `cursorHomeSelect`
3. type cursorLineStart in search  right click on `cursorLineStart` and
   click add shortcut then press Home then enter
4. Do the same for `cursorLineStartSelect` but press shift-Home

Comment: what is the difference between cursorHome and cursorLineStart ? They seem to do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any buiilt-in option to change the current behaviour of the <kbd>Home</kbd> but you change it yourself easily with the help of a macro extension, like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) (in `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "home",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      "cursorHome",
      "cursorHome"
    ]
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Now pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> once has the same effect as pressing it twice.

---

A cleaner way is to give the command `cursorLineStart` the <kbd>Home</kbd> keybinding:

```
  {
    "key": "home",
    "command": "cursorLineStart",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
```

Either do it from the Keybinding Shortcuts or manually add that to your `keybindings.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer by @Mark, this is my `keybindings.json' file which changes the home / end key behaviors to go to the beginning or end of the line when the home or end keys are pressed. This emulates the behavior of vscode in ubuntu.

```
[
  {
    "key": "home",
    "command": "cursorLineStart",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "end",
    "command": "cursorLineEnd",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
]
```