# VS Code: Home key to column 1

Tags: visual-studio-code

Where is the setting so that when I hit Home, the cursor goes to column 1?  I looked in add -ons (It's amusing that you need an add-on to get into overwrite mode when you hit insert) and the add-ons are overrun with other things from "time to stop working" reminders (go home) to home assistant.  I found the setting for the home key, but the function is called "cursorHome".  I imagine there is something like "cursorToColumn1" or "cursorFarLeft", but can't find it.

TIA

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/67129384/836330 .

Comment: have you searched the key binding dialog for `cursor`

Comment: Thanks.  I knew it must certainly be out there and I searched a lot.  Thanks for finding it.